# Store PIG output as Ctrl a delimited output for import into hive?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How do I store PIG output as Ctrl-a delimited output for storage into hive?

Comment: Why not just store the data directly into a Hive table?  ( see `HCatStorer()`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the expected result you can follow below mentioned process 
Store your relation using below command

```
STORE <Relation> INTO '<file_path>' USING PigStorage('\u0001');
```

Expose hive table referring to generated file

```
hive>CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEMP(
c1 INT,
c2 INT,
c3 INT,
c4 INT
.....
)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '<file_path>';
```

If output file present in linux local directory then create table

```
hive>CREATE TABLE TEMP(
c1 INT,
c2 INT,
c3 INT,
c4 INT
.....
)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

and load the data into table

```
hive> load data local inpath '<file_path>' into table temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this?

```
STORE <OutpuRelation> INTO '<Outputfile>' USING PigStorage('\u0001');

Example:
input.txt
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
STORE A INTO 'out' USING PigStorage('\u0001');

Output:
1^A2^A3^A4
5^A6^A7^A8
9^A10^A11^A12
```

UPDATE:
The above pig script output is stored into file name 'part-m-00000' and i am trying to load this file into hive. Everything works fine and i didn't see any issue.

```
hive> create table test_hive(f1 INT,f2 INT,f3 INT,f4 INT);
OK
Time taken: 0.154 seconds

hive> load data local inpath 'part-m-00000' overwrite into table test_hive;
OK
Time taken: 0.216 seconds

hive> select *from test_hive;
OK
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
Time taken: 0.076 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: I have just tested this method and it did not work... any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: Geem7n could you provide some more detail why that didn't work looks pretty standard to me.

Comment: For me its works fine, i am able to load the data into hive.  Are you copying the pig output file into new file and loading into hive (or) loading the same output file generated by pig script into hive?

Comment: I am not getting the ^A separator between each field. Im not able to post my output as it is confidential, but if where using your text file "input.txt" it would look like -> 1234 instead of 1^A2^A3... Is this something to do with defining field parameters?